# How to center a large character over a smaller container?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to center a single character, using CSS, in a `span` which is narrower than the character is.

I have:

```
<span id="A">X</span><span id="B">Y</span><span id="C">Z</span>
```

Where all three spans have

```
display: inline-block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
```

and the Y character in the middle span is larger than the span itself.  I want the character centred over the span, overlapping both the X and the Z.

When the Y is smaller than the span, the following rules work for centring:

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
```

When the Y is wider than the containing box this no longer works: the Y is now shifted to the right.  How do I horizontally center Y when it is wider than the containing box?

(I have tried using `display: table-cell`, suggested in other answers, but this failed because the `width: 32px` was ignored then.)

Here is what I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/seehuhn/hec3xucu/

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  font: bold 32px/32px courier;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#A {
  background: red;
}

#B {
  background: #8f8;
  font-size: 92px;
  color: #F99;
  z-index: 1;
}

#C {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p><span id="A">X</span><span id="B">Y</span><span id="C">Z</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering *anything* is quite simple with CSS flexbox.

```css
p {
  display: flex;               /* 1 */
}

span {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 32px/32px courier;
}

#B {
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 92px;
  color: #F99;
  background: #8f8;
  display: flex;               /* 2 */
  justify-content: center;     /* 3 */
}

#A {
  background: red;
}

#C {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="A">X</span>
  <span id="B">Y</span>
  <span id="C">Z</span>
</p>
```

Notes:

1. Make the primary container a flex container. Now you can use flex alignment properties on child elements. Plus, a flex container lines up all child elements in row, by default.
2. Make the `#B` element a (nested) flex container, so you can apply flex properties to the content (which is technically three levels down in the HTML structure).
3. Use flex properties to horizontally center the content. (If you ever need vertical centering, add `align-items: center`.)

Comment: This works nicely, thanks!  One thing I haven't understood yet: why do I need to make the outer container a flex?  I would have thought that a `<p>` on it's own also "lines up all child elements in a row"; but I tried and clearly this is no longer the case when the children are also flex containers.

Comment: @jochen, You *do not* need to make the outer container flex. However, `display: flex` creates a block level container, so when applied to the child it takes up the entire line. Use `display: inline-flex`.

Comment: The reason you can use `display: flex` on the child when the `p` is a flex container, and everything lines up in a row, is that in flex layout the children of a flex container are forced to line up in a single, non-wrapping line, by default (regardless of their `display` value).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with flex-box

```
  span {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    font: bold 32px/32px courier;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }

  #A {
    background: red;
  }

  #B {
    background: #8f8;
    font-size: 92px;
    color: #F99;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  #C {
    background: blue;
  }
```

If you wanna know more about flex-box click [here](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/).

Comment: I like the flex box demo page you link to :)

Answer (score 1):

You could absolutely position the `Y` over the other 2.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #8f8;
}

span:not(#B) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  font: bold 32px/32px courier;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#A {
  background: red;
  margin-right: 32px;
}

#B {
  font-size: 92px;
  color: #F99;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#C {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p><span id="A">X</span><span id="B">Y</span><span id="C">Z</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution without using a flex box.  It took me a while to spot that the green is now attached to the `<p>` and no longer to the middle `<span>`.